# Gradle - Delete files with certain extension

Tags: gradle

I am using Gradle and would like to delete all files with a certain extension. Is that something Gradle can do?

Comment: Gradle can pretty much do anything that you can script in groovy.  So, the real question is, "is there a gradle **task** that can delete files with a certain extension."  If it isn't written as a task then you don't get the benefit of gradle's task graph (`myBuild.dependsOn('deleteFiles')`) and/or incremental builds.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the Gradle [`Delete`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html) task.

```
task deleteFiles(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('dir/foo') {
        include '**/*.ext'
    }
}
```

Comment: For me this did it: `delete fileTree(dir:'dir/foo', include: '**.ext')` (Gradle 4.1, 2017)

Comment: How can I declare an external method of type delete? i.e. 
ext.deleteFiles = { type: Delete String... fileNames ->
    fileNames.each{  fileName ->
          delete $fileName
    }
}

Comment: @GuerinoRodella no need, there is already a [`project.delete()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#delete-java.lang.Object...-) method for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, but you explanation looks wrong. That is just configuration and does not run until `clean` task called

Answer (score 7):

You may customize default `clean` task to include other directories and files for deletion like:

```
clean{
  delete 'buildDir', 'generated'
}
```

If you want use glob, you may use `fileTree` for example, or any other convenient methods to list files:

```
clean{
  delete 'build', 'target', fileTree(dockerBuildDir) { include '**/*.rpm' }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are seeing?

Comment: Hi @Hubbitus,  I explain it in the my answer ~

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to delete files with certain extension.In general,you must select some files;then filter some of them and finally delete reminding file.For example try this :

```
def tree = fileTree('${SOME_DIR}') 
tree.include '**/*.${SOME_EXT}'
tree.each { it.delete() }
```

Comment: Beware that this is essentially groovy code using gradle's Project.fileTree API.  The code will always be executed during the configuration phase of a gradle build, unless enclosed in a custom task block.

Answer (score 0):

```
clean {
  delete xxxx
}
```

The above clean is not so correct. Because it actually calls a method named `clean` by task name. The kind of method is normally used to configure the task and it happened in the configuration time not in the task-execute time.

The following is a more reasonable way if you need modify the default clean. It's my example to delete all files except one excludes. The delete action in clean task really happen in task-execute time now.

```
    clean {

    Task self = delegate
    self.deleteAllActions()
    self << {

        project.delete(fileTree(dir: buildDir).exclude("**/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent*/**"))

        def emptyDirs = []

        project.fileTree(dir: buildDir).visit {
            File f = it.file

            if (f.isDirectory() ) {
                def children = project.fileTree(f).filter { it.isFile() }.files
                if (children.size() == 0) {
                    emptyDirs << f
                }
            }
        }

        // reverse so that we do the deepest folders first
        emptyDirs.reverseEach {
            println "delete file: " + it + ", " + project.delete(it) //it.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So hard... Why not just use `doLast`? And what incorrect with `clean { delete xxxx }` it is not called if you not call task `clean`

Comment: Becuase the default clean task have included default delete actions. we need deleteAllActions(). self << { the action is just my situation, normally people can delete the file as they want }.  clean { delete xxxx } will call delete if you not call task clean?   I think the closure is called at the configuration time.

Comment: Please try, if it is not clean task, it is not run. It is just task configuration

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
// Include only files that have the '.ext' extension
project.delete(fileTree(dir: './path/to/directory', include: "**.ext"))
```

I was able to call this at the top-level of my Gradle file and didn't have to use any form of `clean` task.

You can even move up and out of the current base-level directory to an adjacent directory using `../sibling-directory-name`.