# How do I extend gradle's clean task to delete a file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

So far I've added the following to my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'base' 
clean << {
    delete '${rootDir}/api-library/auto-generated-classes/'
    println '${rootDir}/api-library/auto-generated-classes/'
}
```

However, not only is my file not deleted, but the print statement shows that `${rootDir}` is not being converted to the root directory of my project.

Why won't this work, what concepts am I missing?

Answer (score 70):

You just need to use double quotes. Also, drop the `<<` and use `doFirst` instead if you are planning to do the deletion during execution. Something like this:

```
clean.doFirst {
    delete "${rootDir}/api-library/auto-generated-classes/"
    println "${rootDir}/api-library/auto-generated-classes/"
}
```

Gradle build scripts are written in Groovy DSL. In Groovy you need to use double quotes for string interpolation (when you are using `${}` as placeholders). Take a look at [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_double_quoted_string).

Comment: Not sure about it. It will be deleting the file at *configuration* phase, not during execution.

Comment: The above comment is not true. doFirst is only evaluated during the `execution` phase. 

_The calls doFirst and doLast can be executed multiple times. They add an action to the beginning or the end of the task’s actions list. When the task **executes**, the actions in the action list are executed in order._ [from docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)

Answer (score 63):

`<<`  is equivalent for `clean.doLast`. 
`doFirst` and `doLast` are ordering the operations at the *execution* phase,
which is seldom relevant for delete operations.

In this case you don't need any of them. 
The clean task from base is of type [Delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Delete.html),
so you simply need to pass it a closure to tell it at *configuration* time what to delete when it executes:

```
clean {
    delete 'someFile'
}
```

AS [mushfek0001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813360/740641) correctly points it out in his answer, you should use double quotes for variable interpolation to work:

```
clean {
    delete "${buildDir}/someFile"
}
```

You need to have at least the base plugin applied for this to work, most other plugins, like the Java plugin either apply base or declare their own 
`clean` task of type delete [Delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Delete.html) task. The error you would get if you don't have this is a missing `clean` method one.

```
apply plugin: 'base'
```

Comment: `delete '${buildDir}/someFile'` will not resolve the variable for `buildDir`. You need to use `"` here, e.g. `delete "$buildDir/someFile"`

Comment: corrected the typo of `'` to `"`. Double wuotes are requried for [GStrings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html)

Comment: But this way you completely replace the default behavior of clean. What if he has some more tasks attached to it?

Comment: As pointed out in the documentation, the `delete` method of the `Delete` task:

  > Adds some files to be deleted by this task.

As such, this does not replace previous behavior ( i.e. previous list of files to delete ), it just adds to it.

Comment: This results in an error for me: `Could not find method clean() for arguments [build_6vh7849xb7rs3m0ite221ir66$_run_closure6@20f01807]`

Comment: if you want to delete many files use `delete fileTree(dir: "${projectDir}", include: '**.ext')`
See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27285885/3495031

Answer (score 20):

In order to extend the clean task, you can use

```
clean.doFirst {}
```

or

```
clean.doLast {}
```

These will allow you to inject your own actions into the clean process.  In order to delete files and directories you can use the "file" API which doesn't require any additional plugins.

Here is an example that will delete both a file and a directory as the last step in the clean task:

```
clean.doLast {
    file('src/main/someFile.txt').delete()
    file('src/main/libs').deleteDir()
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Gradle Kotlin Script analogue:

```
tasks {
    getByName<Delete>("clean") {
        delete.add("logs") // add accepts argument with Any type
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get the `clean` task by index: `tasks["clean"]...`

Answer (score 12):

Below one works for me (I prefer to use `dependsOn`),

```
task customCleanUp(type:Delete) {
   delete "your_folder", "your_file"
}

tasks.clean.dependsOn(tasks.customCleanUp)
```

Comment: It's important that the task is build with possibility of passing in parameters [Authoring Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks). This way it's easy to register a new task of a particular type and then just define your own inputs. While if task reads gradle properties directly in the action itself and you don't have option to overwrite those, maybe you won't manage to copy/duplicate it and will have to rewrite the logic in TaskAction.

Answer (score 1):

There are options in gradle where you can extend a particular task ("clean" in your case) with doFirst (before the actual task), doLast (after the actual task).

You just need to replace single quotes with double quotes.

```
clean.doFirst {
    delete "${rootDir}/api-library/auto-generated-classes"
    println "${rootDir}/api-library/auto-generated-classes"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
tasks.clean {
    delete += listOf(
        "${rootDir}/logs.txt",
        projectDir.list()?.first { it/* name */ .contains("temp") }
    )
}
```

This deletes a file called *logs.txt* at the project root and deletes any directory/file that has `temp` in its name in this subproject (the folder containing this build file).