# How to delete files in a directory on a grails script using gradle

Tags: grails, gradle

I understand Grails 3 uses gradle for scripting, I'm trying to delete the files in a directory, but I can't accomplish it.

If I type 
`delete "grails-app/assets/stylesheets/a.css` it works

but if I try something like 
`delete "grails-app/assets/stylesheets/*.css` it does nothing.

Any idea why?

Comment: There are a lot of answers in google. The first of them (by keywords "gradle delete files wildcard"):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285885/gradle-delete-files-with-certain-extension

Comment: I've tried those before posting, but none of that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the method from the link I've posted as the comment.
I've added the next lines and all works perfectly.

```
task deleteFiles(type: Delete, group: "StackOverflow example") {
    delete fileTree("$projectDir/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/") {
        include '**/*.css'
    }
}
```

You may also delete files without subdirs recursion if you needed.

```
include '*.css'
```

You may even write any Groovy/Java code in the Gradle script to do that task in other way if you don't like it.